# General information on trackerless bittorrent such as BitTorrent's Mainline DHT

Tags: protocols, bittorrent, dht

I'm curious as to how trackerless torrents work. I tried to search for information (presentations or something) about the DHT torrent protocol but couldn't find any valuable resources.

Could someone please provide a description or a link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do BitTorrent magnet links work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844502/how-do-bittorrent-magnet-links-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is the Wikipedia [Distributed Hash Table](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table) page as an introduction.  I don't think you're likely to find anything specific to how BitTorrent would use it, but there are known implementations of a DHT: [Pastry](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastry_%28DHT%29) and [Chord](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28DHT%29).

I've read through the [academic paper](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/chord/papers/paper-ton.pdf) describing Chord and it gave me a pretty good idea of how the general DHT algorithm worked.  And a [slideshow](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F06/lectures/21-p2p.ppt) from Carnegie Mellon starts talking about DHT on slide 37.

Of course, if you are looking for precisely how BitTorrent does it, you'd probably need to grab their reference implementation and look through the code.

Answer (score 1):

Bittorrent uses its own DHT implementation called [Mainline DHT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29#Distributed_trackers) which is based off [Kademlia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia).

**Editor note:** *The majority of DHT torrent clients use MDHT, but Azureus (now called Vuze) uses its own version called [ADHT](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Distributed_hash_table) which is different in behavior and incompatible with MDHT.*

Answer (score 1):

I found the academic papers and DHT implementations to be very inaccessible. The following 2 links were sufficient to get my own implementation up and running. Read the first completely, and refer to the second  when you need clarification.

- [BEP 5 DHT Protocol](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html)
- [Wikipedia: Kademlia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia)

When in doubt, just make it up. Improve it later. DHT is horribly complicated to coordinate.

Comment: For bittorrent the "just make it up" part has resulted in many poorly performing implementations since people did not understand some of the more subtle behaviors. The Kademlia design is very resilient so it's not the end of the world, but reading the papers and maybe studying existing implementations is necessary to make a good implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[Mainline DHT](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_DHT) on Wikipedia is a concise outline and description of the protocol. You can also read the [design document](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html).

Answer (score 1):

A very good presentation with video and slides on how BitTorrent DHT works can be found here: [BitTorrent Tech Talks: DHT](http://engineering.bittorrent.com/2013/01/22/bittorrent-tech-talks-dht/)
The talk is done by [Arvid Norberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657930/arvid),
Chief Architect at BitTorrent, Inc
and the [libtorrent/rasterbar](http://libtorrent.org/) developer.