# Is it possible to include peers in trackerless torrent file?

Tags: tracker, dht, torrent

Can I generate torrent file that already has peers inside without using trackers, open trackers, dht and peer exchange?

If yes, how can I do that?

The reason I want to do that, is that I want to get peers by DHT and pass that peers to another torrent client that do not supports DHT or peer exchange, and cannot get peers without trackers.

I found this, but I don't understand what is nodes, and if it's what I am searching for.
http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html#torrent-file-extensions

And please do not advice me to use uTorrent trackerless torrent functionality where it utorrent becomes a tracker. I am not mistaken in what I need and my question is correct.

Comment: Why is  BEP 5 not exactly what you're looking for? Add a 'nodes'. Get the torrent from dht.. it may already contain nodes.. if not, decode the metainfo, insert the nodes list... Recode and pass that to the torrent client.. if it supports bep 5 it should be able to use those nodes instead of the announce URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no, that is not possible.
What client is it? Does it not have support to manualy add peers?

Another metod would be to do it the other way round and manualy add your peer to a PEX capable client and then it would be passed around to other PEX capable clients.

Nodes in torrent files is used as one of many ways to bootstrap the DHT. Explained [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999786/how-pex-protocol-magnetic-links-finds-it-first-ip/11089702#11089702)

The only thing comming close to what you want to do is [webseeds - BEP19](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0019.html), but it's not applicable in this case.

Comment: thanks for answer, will search for other workarounds