# Direct connection bittorrent transfer C or Ruby libtorrent

Tags: c, ruby, network-programming, p2p, bittorrent

Is it possible to craft a torrent file in such a way that it will bypass a tracker via assigning an IP address of the server hosting the file instead?

I am interested in bittorrents file transfer protocol via `libtorrent` and they way it downloads files as pieces in such a way that you get an exact corruption free duplicate on the other side, but I would like to bypass the tracker since the files will always be located at one location.

If this is not possible is there any other protocols/libraries I can look into that can be implemented in C, C++ or Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using the bittorrent protocol, you can do it by creating a .torrent file with a webseed in it. [WebSeed - HTTP/FTP Seeding (GetRight style) - BEP19](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0019.html)

Then you use a ordinary HTTP or FTP server to host the file(s).
(Use the IP direct in the URL if you want.)

The downloading can be done with any bittorrent client.

It is not possible to put the address to a peer (bittorrent client) in the .torrent file. See: [Is it possible to include peers in trackerless torrent file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28705952/3693974)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Does using this webseed function of the protocol still include the chucking and file corruption protections just like a normal torrent transfer? If it does and I can find a way to easily create the torrent file with a webseed this would solve all my problems!

Comment: Yes, it does. Many .torrent creators has a possibility to include webseeds.

Answer (score 0):

> but I would like to bypass the tracker since the files will always be located at one location.

If you're implementing your own client using libtorrent for the purpose of 1:1 transfers you probably can inject the remote host's IP and port explicitly.

I don't think it makes all that much sense to try to twiddle with the torrent file if you are building your own client anyway.

Comment: Well I am looking for a linux application that has a similar protocol (multi connections for transfers, checksums on parts) for 1:1 copies of files. Can you believe that after a few days I haven't found one yet. I am breaking down to the point where I am about to write one myself. With or without libtorrent type libraries. I'll do some tests to see if simply adding the host to the file will fly with normal torrent clients.

Comment: is rsync not enough for your needs? it hashes the content too to verify integrity. I think there also are multicast based file transfer tools if you need bulk distribution in a managed network.