# How to perform a BitTorrent handshake given an infohash and it's peers?

Tags: python, p2p, bittorrent, dht, torrent

I'd like to continue my [last related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74312036/how-to-download-a-torrent-knowing-only-its-infohash-and-peers) in my attempt to understand and build a BitTorrent search engine. While listening the network for "get_peers" messages, I manage to grab infohashes. I proceed to ask the corresponding DHT node for it's peers. In my understanding in order to find out if the infohash is valid, (for starters) I have to send a BitTorrent handshake to the peers and compare the responses. However, besides the connection refused errors which I ignore for now, most peers reply with empty responses. Am I doing something wrong here? Note that the following code samples are not a great implementation, I just want to understand the flow.

**Handshake function:**

```py
import socket 

def handshake(infohash, peer):
    peer_id = b"-TR2940-k8hj0wgej6ch"

    handshake = b'\x13'
    handshake += b'BitTorrent protocol'
    handshake += b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00'
    handshake += infohash
    handshake += peer_id

    try:
        ClientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        ClientSocket.settimeout(3)
        ClientSocket.connect(peer)
        print("Connected to peer.")
        ClientSocket.sendall(handshake)
        response = ClientSocket.recv(68)

        if not response:
            print("Empty response.")
            return
        print(f"Handshake completed, resp: {response}")

        ClientSocket.close()        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**Utilities to get peers from given infohash and DHT node:**

```py
import random
import uuid
import bencode
import socket
from struct import unpack
import handshake

def newTID(tidlen):
    tid = ""
    for i in range(0, tidlen):
        tid += chr(random.randint(97, 122))
    return tid

def newID():
  return uuid.uuid4().hex[0:20]

def split_nodes(nodes):
    length = len(nodes)
    if (length % 26) != 0:
        return
    for i in range(0, length, 26):
        nid = nodes[i:i+20]
        ip = socket.inet_ntoa(nodes[i+20:i+24])
        port = unpack("!H", nodes[i+24:i+26])[0]
        yield nid, ip, port

UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
UDPClientSocket.settimeout(4)

def get_peers_from_infohash(infohash, node):
    get_peers_query = {"t":"aa", "y":"q", "q":"get_peers", "a": {"id":newID(), "info_hash":infohash}}
    get_peers_query = bencode.encode(get_peers_query)
    
    UDPClientSocket.sendto(get_peers_query, node)

    received = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(65536)
    msg = received[0]
    decoded = bencode.decode(msg)

    peers = split_nodes(decoded["r"]["nodes"])
    for nid, ip, port in peers:
        print(infohash, infohash.hex(),  ip, port)
        handshake.handshake(infohash, (ip, port))
```

My DHT crawler:

```py
import bencode
import socket
import uuid
from struct import unpack
import threading
import random
import dhtutils

def newTID(tidlen):
    tid = ""
    for i in range(0, tidlen):
        tid += chr(random.randint(97, 122))
    return tid

def newID():
  return uuid.uuid4().hex[0:20]

def handle_message(msg, node):
    if msg.get("e"):
        # print(msg.get("e"))
        pass
    elif msg.get("y") == "r":
       handle_response(msg, node)
    elif msg.get("y") == "q":
        handle_query(msg, node)

def handle_query(msg, node):
    try:
        if msg["q"] == "get_peers":
            infohash = msg["a"]["info_hash"]
            # print(infohash.hex(), msg, node)
            print(infohash.hex())
            dhtutils.get_peers_from_infohash(infohash, node)
    except:
        pass

def handle_response(msg, node):
    global all_nodes
    if msg.get("r").get("nodes"):
        # response from find_nodes
        nodes = msg.get("r").get("nodes")
        if nodes:
            nodes = split_nodes(nodes)
            for id, ip, port in nodes:
                find_nodes(id, (ip, port))
                all_nodes.append((id, (ip, port)))
    elif msg.get("t") == "pg":
        # response from ping
        id = msg["r"]["id"]
        all_nodes.append((id, node))

def split_nodes(nodes):
    length = len(nodes)
    if (length % 26) != 0:
        return
    for i in range(0, length, 26):
        nid = nodes[i:i+20]
        ip = socket.inet_ntoa(nodes[i+20:i+24])
        port = unpack("!H", nodes[i+24:i+26])[0]
        yield nid, ip, port

def find_nodes(id, node):
    global UDPClientSocket
    find_node_query = {"t":newTID(2), "y":"q", "q":"find_node", "a": {"id":newID(), "target":id}}
    find_node_query = bencode.encode(find_node_query)
    UDPClientSocket.sendto(find_node_query, node)

def ping(node):
    global UDPClientSocket
    ping_query = {"t":"pg", "y":"q", "q":"ping", "a":{"id":newID()}}
    ping_query = bencode.encode(ping_query)
    UDPClientSocket.sendto(ping_query, node)

def listen():
    while True:
        try:
            received = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(65536)
            msg = received[0]
            src = received[1]
            decoded = bencode.decode(msg)
            handle_message(decoded, src)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

T = threading.Thread(target=listen)
T.start()

nodes = [
    ("router.bittorrent.com", 6881),
    ("dht.transmissionbt.com", 6881),
    ("router.utorrent.com", 6881)
]

for node in nodes:
    ping(node)

all_nodes = []

while True:
    if len(all_nodes) > 0:
       for node in all_nodes:
           find_nodes(node[0], node[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DHT lookup is incorrect since you're looking at the `nodes` response field which contains DHT nodes used for finding other DHT nodes when performing an iterative lookup in the DHT.
It is not the `values` field that contains bittorrent contacts.

You're only going to get the latter when you have properly routed to the target region that covers an infohash in the DHT keyspace.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. Can you suggest a proper way of doing that? Maybe a resource I could take a look? This is the first time I hear about something like this. I thought the process was simpler.

Comment: In addition to BEP5 you should also read the kademlia paper: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~petar/papers/maymounkov-kademlia-lncs.pdf

Comment: I thank you again for your time, I'll study it (and come back with more questions of course).

Comment: Edit: It appears I attached wrong code snippets in the crawler part. Fixed it with the original "incorrect" lookup I intended to upload.